# Can I bend CPVC like I do with PVC (heat gun)

Tags: pipe, pvc

I'm working with some CPVC for hot water and now I need to make some adjust for better placement. With PVC I would just heat a bit to remove any possible stress or to put it into a more adequate position, can the same be done with CPVC?

Comment: I would not heat bend PVC type pipes. The heat levels needed to bend the pipe in this way changes the pipe properties. It has been by experience that the process tends to harden the pipe and make it more brittle. If you really need flexible water piping look into PEX.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, since you're dealing with heat & pressure & really don't want to screw around with the already somewhat marginal properties of the piping.

Try it at your own peril, but I'd suggest throwing in a 45 or less fitting to accomplish the slight offset. Two 45's (or less) might be needed so you can twist them for the perfect dry-fit & marking before gluing.

Comment: In some cases 2 45° might work, but most times (when bending is considered) it is more trouble. If I want to offset a pipe 1 meter long some 2-3 cm to the right, bending is the way to go. Using other pieces of joints is literally gambling and you could end up with something that is crooked in another axis.

Comment: As long as you understand you'll be messing with the pipe's properties. Quicker is rarely better & doing another pair of 45's for another axis would still be more proper. Do you have other fitting options? Lesser bends are available & actual offsets do exist, but you'll need to go to a plumbing supplier for them.

Comment: The smaller fittings available are 45, and then 90.

Comment: Well, bend away then & pressure & heat test everything before you cover it over, if there's no way that fittings can work. I'll keep my fingers crossed, so you shouldn't have any issues for 29.642 months.

Comment: There are small tube bladders you can put into pvc/cpvc and inflate with air. The heat needs to be moved around the pipe and several inches to either side this is how I have had to make very unusual bends but a couple of 15 or 30 degree couplings would be much cheaper.

Comment: I wouldn't doubt it, but I would doubt CPVC's abilities after any "treatment". The stuff doesn't even match or compete with the cheapo low-grade type M copper. I mean it's all fine for the worthless culture that's only concerned about their time in some place. But, I'm not with those turds who also use the Shark-bite garbage as permanent behind wall connections.